# assigning const array pointer to non const array pointer

Tags: c++, pointers, constants

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
          const int l_loc[3] = {1,2,3};
          int (*l_loc2)[3] = NULL;
          l_loc2 = const_cast<int (*)[3]>(l_loc);   // complaining here. 
          std::cout<<l_loc2[1]<<std::endl;
                   return 0;
}
```

./example.cpp:7: error: invalid const_cast from type ‘const int*’ to type ‘int (*)[3]’

I can modify only that pointed line. any clue please.

Comment: `l_loc` decays to a `int const*`, while you want **its** address.

Comment: An array isn't a pointer!

Comment: This will compile: [`l_loc2 = const_cast<int (*)[3]>(&l_loc);`](https://ideone.com/Gm8Skw)

Comment: simply remove the line and `std::cout << l_loc[1];` ... not really clear what is the purpose of this exercise

Comment: @tobi303 UB-flirting aerobatics maybe?

Comment: @tobi303 - Probably an exam/interview question

Comment: @StoryTeller one day I should enter an interview, just to see the face of the interviewer when I tell him that I refuse to work on something like that. Happy to be not a professional :P

Comment: @tobi303 - Admirable. But thankfully, the companies that ask such questions become fewer and fewer.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
          const int l_loc[3] = {1,2,3};
          int (*l_loc2)[3] = NULL;
          l_loc2 = const_cast<int (*)[3]>(l_loc);   // complaining here. 
          std::cout<<l_loc2[1]<<std::endl;
                   return 0;
}
```

`l_loc` is a pointer to the first integer in the array. The address it contains is constant. You can't reassign `l_loc` to point to another array of integer constants. Which is why you must also cast the address of `l_loc`. So instead of `l_loc2 = const_cast<int (*)[3]>(l_loc)` you need to pass the address of `l_loc` i.e. `&l_loc`. Result `l_loc2 = const_cast<int (*)[3]>(&l_loc)` I hope this helps.